# Facebook Tokens - I created a never-expiring token, but how?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I have been trying to create a never-expiring Facebook Token (ideally programatically) and have not been able to do so, then, without really trying, on a different Facebook Application, I managed to create a token which, according to

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?version=v2.5&q={TOKEN}`

will never expire and I can't replicate it on any other Facebook Apps or for any other Facebook Tokens.

I can programatically (PHP) take the short lived token (1/2 hours) and extend it to 60 days, but I wanted to ideally get a never-expire token.

I guess I'm not asking how I managed to do it, but I can't find any explanation or documentation nor reason as to why I was able to achieve this for one token, but not any others.

Is it something in the App itself while it was created? Is there actually a way to get a never-expiring token, even though I've followed many of the guides online yet can only get a 1/2 hour token converted to 60 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there actually a way to get a never-expiring token

No, not *really*. Even what you think is a never-expiring token *can* expire - f.e. if the user who created it changes their account password.

> I guess I'm not asking how I managed to do it, but I can't find any explanation or documentation nor reason as to why I was able to achieve this for one token, but not any others.

It is not documented, because Facebook wants you to use the 60 day tokens, when you app is acting on behalf of a personal user profile. They removed `offline_access` permission ages ago, specifically so that apps the user has long forgotten about can’t act on their behalf or still access their data any more.

So if you are writing an app that acts on behalf of users, you should really rather make do with the 60 day token - that should be enough for most cases.

---

Now what you are seeing with your token here, is a side effect of how Facebook has implemented extended page access tokens. Those do not have a default expiry - but they need to be invalidated when the user is removed as a page admin. Therefor, they are internally tied to the user token that was used to request the page token. User token gets invalidated - page access token becomes invalid together with it. And that in turn requires that the user token does not automatically expire after 60 days.

So, when you extend a user token that includes `manage_pages` permission, you will get an extended token with “unlimited” validity. But, again, that is a side effect of current implementation only, and can change in the future.

Comment: Thank you, very informative. As a side question to your answer, at the end where you manage_pages, are you suggesting that if this permission is included, it 'may' be possible to get a never-ending token? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Yes. But again, don’t rely on it to always be the case in the future.